# How do i post model attribute POJO object to spring controller using angular js

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to angular JS, spring mvc.

Basically I am trying to post form data  on my portal through angular JS as a model attribute POJO object to spring controller.

How do it go about it?  You can find below the sample data that i require from the FORM and the angular JS function add() that works on ng-submit on the form.

```
@RequestMapping(value="sample", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSampleForm(@ModelAttribute("checkInRequest") CheckInRequest checkInRequest, 
@ModelAttribute("sampleRequest") SampleRequestMO sampleRequest,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
throws Exception
```

<------Angular JS---->

```
$scope.add = function(){
    var request = $http({
    method: "post",
            url: "sample.htm",
            transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
            sampleRequest: {
                'phone': 9999999999,
                'name': "Kim"
            },
            CheckInRequest: {
                'merchantCode': 11,
                'outletCode': 100

            }
        });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

When you're sending data over $http post you're sending jsons, not model attributes. Model attributes (as Spring sees them) are submitted forms. You should be able to find `CheckInRequest` in request params.

```
@RequestMapping(value="sample", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSampleForm(@RequestParam("CheckInRequest") String checkInRequest, @RequestParam("sampleRequest") String sampleRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
```

Note that without further configuration the params will be received as strings (representing json) and you have to deserialize them manually. You can go further and configure an `ObjectMapper` or a binder to have them deserialized by Spring.

Comment: Hey Thanks for a quick reply.  I do not want JSONs at the controller end from the UI. is  it possible to get a model attribute object?